# Polar Coordinate Multi variable Analysis

Tags: real-analysis

$\iint_D \mu(u,v) \,dA$ where D is a disk of radius 1, hence can be represented $u^2+v^2 \leq 1$

How does one show that:
$\iint_D f(u,v) \,dA \leq \frac{1}{3} \pi M $
where M is the following:
$$ 
\\
\max_{(u,v)\in D} \sqrt{|f_u|^2+|f_v|^2}$$

Thought thus far: To use polar coordinates, hence represent $u,v$ as $r\cos\theta$ and $r\sin\theta$ respectively. However, I am still confused as to how this square root somehow provides a bound for the function. Any insight would be appreciated

Comment: how $\mu$ and $f$ are related?

Comment: f is a function of u and v, i accidentally changed it to f at the end there

Comment: for added clarity it is worth noting that on the boundary of the disk, f is identically zero, hence the set is jordan measurable. Furthermore f is continuously differentiable on the interior of the disk. I apologize for not stating such assumption since being concise is very important

Comment: What if $f = 100$? isn't $f_u$ the derivative$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial u}$?

Comment: Great point, I will bring this up to my professor. Perhaps the question must have an added assumption of non-constant f? Will then this inequality hold?

Comment: Although I have not calculated, but 100+0.1cos($\theta$) might have a same problem. I think f would be replaced by |f -<f>| or something else.

Comment: UPDATE: after discussing with some peers, the statement above is indeed true however it was lack of clarity on my part in formulating the question. The boundary condition being that $f$ is identically zero on the boundary, as well as the fact $f$ is continuously differentiable on the interior of the disk AND continuous on the disk, which does not allow us to let $f$ be a constant, other than in the identically zero case (trivial). I apologize for not stating all conditions needed for the above statement to be true

Comment: The real proof actually follow relatively simply from multivariable mean value theorem where one uses the gradient, since M is simply the norm of the gradient. If anyone is curious, I can type the solution up this weekend when I have time. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem now seems to make sense. Here is  another simple solution.

$$\iint_D f(u,v) \,dA = \iint_D \frac{\partial u}{\partial u} f(u,v) \,dA = -\iint_D u\frac{\partial}{\partial u}(f(u,v)) \,dA + \iint_D \frac{\partial}{\partial u}( u f(u,v)) \,dA \\ = -\iint_D u\, f_u \,dA +\int_{\partial D} u\, f \,dv  \quad \text{(Green's Theorem)}\\= -\iint_D u\, f_u \,dA \quad (f\,\big|_{\partial D} = 0) $$

Then, 
$$
\text{since} \quad \iint_D f(u,v) \,dA = -\frac{1}{2}\iint_D u\, f_u + v\,f_v\,dA \quad,
\\ \, \\ \iint_D f(u,v) \,dA \leq  \frac{1}{2}\iint_D |u\, f_u + v\,f_v|\,dA \leq \frac{1}{2}\iint_D \sqrt{u^2 + v^2}\,|\nabla f|\,dA  \leq \frac{M}{2} \int_{0}^{1} r \,\, 2\pi r dr = \frac{1}{3} \pi M\,.
$$